# SQL server query for pulling data from child table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I have a table called  Identifier which has identifierType, identifierValue and foreignkey to patient table.

One patient can have multiple identifiers so for a given patient there will be multiple rows in identifier table.

I want to pull value  of patientforeign key from this table which meets given criteria,

one example is I want to find

```
patientId where identifierType = 'PatientFirst" 
and identifierValue = 'sally' 
and identifierType= 'patientFirst' 
and identifier value = 'sally'.
```

what will be sql statement to pull this result in sqlserver

References : ( http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/33fc6/2/0 )

Comment: I think I figured out. I want to pull based upon multiple criteria so I think something like this will work in my case :

select fk_patientId from Identifier where IdentifierType= 'PatientLast' and identifiervalue= 'doe'
and fk_patientId in ( select fk_patientid from identifier where IdentifierType = 'PatientFirst' and identifiervalue ='sally')

Answer (score 0):

Seems a bit easy for this website, no? :)

```
SELECT fk_patientID 
FROM identifier
WHERE IdentifierType = 'PatientFirst'
AND IdentifierValue = 'sally'
```

Comment: Thanks Noah but I needed to pull based upon multiple identifiers.I think I figured it out and have posted my solution as comment above.

Answer (score 0):

Pivot table may be useful to you as well if you'd like to flatten certain properties into a single row per patient ID:

```
;with PatientFullName( fk_patientId, PatientLast, PatientFirst )
as
(
  select
    fk_patientId
    , pt.PatientLast
    , pt.PatientFirst
  from
    Identifier
    pivot
    (
      MAX(identifierValue)
      for identifierType in ( [PatientLast], [PatientFirst] )
    ) as pt
)

select
  *
from
  PatientFullName pfn
where
  pfn.PatientLast = 'Doe'
  and pfn.PatientFirst = 'Sally'
```